# Query for all values that appear every day

Tags: mysql

I've got a logs table with dates attached to the log items themselves. The log tracks the impressions from ad spaces used by publishers to display ads. It looks (greatly simplified) like this:

```
id | date | adspace_id | impressions
```

When an adspace has no impressions for a day, it will sometimes deliver a 0. Other times, it's simply not logged. Other times, the adspace_id will be logged several times o the same date.  (I do not know why.) I'm trying to pull adspace_ids that have a value for every day over a 30 day period, but can't figure out how to do this. I've tried

```
SELECT adspace_id FROM logstbl WHERE (`date` > "2014-02-01" AND `date` < "2014-03-02") AND impressions != 0
```

But it pulls any space with a log between those dates rather than a space with logs on **all** of them.

I think I'm missing something, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count how many days there are between those dates (for example, 30 days) and look for id's with that many dates assigned to them (this SQL can almost certainly be refactored, but just an idea):

```
SELECT adspace_id from
(
    SELECT adspace_id, count(date) as cnt from
    (
        SELECT distinct adspace_id, date 
        FROM logstbl WHERE (`date` > "2014-02-01" AND `date` < "2014-03-02") 
        AND impressions != 0
    ) a group by adspace_id
) b where b.cnt > 30
```